# Pad the month with '0'

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

This is my code:

```
If FinalMonth = "" OR FinalYear = ""  Then
    FinalMonth = Month(Now())
    FinalYear = Year(Now())
End If

Select Case(FinalMonth)
    Case "01","03","05","07","08","10","12"
        FinalDay = "31"
    Case "04","06","09","11"
        FinalDay = "30"
    Case "02"
        If ( (FinalYear Mod 4) <> 0 ) Then
            FinalDay = "28"
        Else
            FinalDay = "29"
        End If
End Select
```

I want to set my month with 0 before the number 1 (January) per example, and finally Month 01. How can I do it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can;

```vbs
If FinalMonth = "" OR FinalYear = ""  Then
    FinalMonth = Month(Now())
    FinalYear = Year(Now())
End If

'get last day of month - add 1 month then deduct 1 day
FinalDay = Day(DateSerial(FinalYear, FinalMonth + 1, 1) - 1)

'pad month
if (FinalMonth < 10) then FinalMonth = "0" & FinalMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this ?

```
<%=Right("0" & Day(now()), 2)%>-<%=Right("0" & Month(now()), 2)%>-<%=Year(now())%>
```

Output : 10-02-2018